# Redirect Nginx only if params are not present

Tags: nginx

Here's my requirement for redirecting in Nginx -

```
Redirect Example
1. www.example.com/gaming.html -> www.example.com/gaming-zone.html

No Redirect example (when params are present, dont redirect)
2. www.example.com/gaming.html?name=foo -> www.example.com/gaming.html?name=foo
```

I have a very simple redirect setup up -

```
rewrite ^/gaming.html$ /gaming-zone.html redirect;
```

which satisfies example 1 but  redirects example 2 as well. Can someone please share how to fix the rule so that URLs containing params are not redirected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not seem you tried to at least try to get information....

According to the nginx http core module [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables). You can use either $is_args or $args or $arg_name.

Hence you can simply use the following line:

```
if($is_args = ""){
    rewrite ^/gaming.html$ /gaming-zone.html redirect;
}
```

Since you want the second url not to change, there is no need to do anything with that url.